# Formal salutation of a servant to a child?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, contemporary-english, salutations

Let's say I have someone like [Alfred Pennyworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Pennyworth). Such a person would obviously address the man and woman of the house as "Sir" and "Madam". (For example, "Would sir care for a beverage?")

How could this hypothetical person address a very small child?

The "traditional" answer seems to be "master <name>", but this seems really odd for a really young (possibly only just learning to talk) child. In Spanish, it would be "señorito" rather than "señor", but I'm not aware of a direct English equivalent.

The best I've been able to come up with is "the boy". Is there anything else, or am I stuck with either "master" or "the boy"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108996/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-formal-salutation-of-a-servant-to-a-child).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of this until now...

"Madame", obviously, comes from "my dame (lady)", "milord" (and variants) from "my lord"...

...so what's a boy? A **lad**. So, the address "my *lad*" (or "milad", or "m'lad") could work. (For a girl, this would of course by "m'lass".) There is, of course, Scottish precedent for this.

Another option, if some neologizing is permitted, would be to look to the French roots of such expressions, from which we might derive "monfils" ("my son") or "monjeune" ("my youth" / "my youngster"). In this case, the address for adults should probably stick to the more fully French "monsieur" and "madame".

Answer (score 0):

Master was a jest to display parenthood and abuse the child in plain sight because tender and being able defeated the elderly but the need to be cared for was evident if you research common scenes you will learn that the word common sense was created to overthrow the use of child in law and order.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

They say it is minor as 'Minor will you please' as (sir your power are)? but most refences are tender and the control of a union or marriage. The minor power of the world.
It is where the WILL, WANT and PLEUSE as pleasure' came into existence in the written world.

Comment: A Google books search for the phrase "Minor will you please" over the period 1800 to 2002 turns up zero matches for the expression in any situation where "Minor" is being used as a form of address to a child—by anyone. If you are correct that "Minor" is sometimes used as a formal salutation by a servant to a child, there should be some instances of its use in the print record that you can cite in support of your answer. Please consider supplementing your answer with one or more such examples.

Answer (score -2):

> Such a person would obviously address the man and woman of the house as "Sir" and "Madam". (For example, "Would sir care for a beverage?")

Obviously you do not have servants in the UK. That is not how a butler would address his employer today. A good butler will provide the drink without being asked or an ordinary one will wait until asked. The use of "Sir", is not necessary, neither is the stilted "care for".

> How could this hypothetical person address a very small child?

By its name: "Hello, John, your father says it's time for bed."